# Get Generated Query From SQLiteDatabase.execSQL

Tags: java, android, debugging, sqlite

I've this line of codes:

```
String insertSQL = "INSERT INTO " + BOOK_NAME
        + " (id, title, date, type, excerpt, content, category_id, category_name"
        + " ,permalink, guid, time, reporter) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
database.execSQL(
        insertSQL,
        new Object[] { 
                book.getNewsID(), 
                book.getTitle(),
                book.getDate(),
                book.getType(),
                book.getExcerpt(),
                book.getContent(),
                book.getCategoryID(),
                book.getCategoryName(),
                book.getPermalink(),
                book.getGUID(),
                book.getTime(),
                book.getReporter()
                });
```

My question is, is there a way to get the raw query from this method?
I've quite a bunch code like this and I want to debug what is the actual query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is, is there a way to get the raw query from this method?

There is no "raw query". A query is a `SELECT` statement, or something else that returns a result set. This is an `INSERT` statement.

If you mean "raw SQL statement", then no, that is not available. I am not even certain a full SQL statement is even generated -- the `?` stuff may be handled inside SQLite itself.

Comment: fair enough. I guess I'll have to create the query myself so that I can debug it.